# Outlook 2016 rule for BCC received

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2016

My outlook at work was recently upgraded. I believe it is 2016 version. How do I create a rule to highlight emails in which I am a bcc recipient?

I see rules for me being in the To field or the CC field, but not the BCC field.

An old forum post mentioned creating a rule for times when I am NOT in either To or CC, but it does not appear this rule for 'except' scenarios exists in outlook 2016.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is no BCC field in email messages, at least not in the systems I have used. You therefore cannot reference it. Try sending one to yourself and look at the headers.

Comment: @Bib, there is. New message, ... and you will see "Show Fields" Bcc:

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848804/how-to-set-a-outlook-rule-to-classify-email-received-by-bcc

Comment: @RomeoNinov I and the op is talking about the received message. There is no BCC field defined in the headers.

Comment: @Bib, you miss the part "received" in comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34523541/2908599) in SO:

Create rule where:

```
Apply this rule after the message arrives 
where my name in not in the To Box
move it to [folderOfYourChoice] folder 
except where my name is in the Cc box
```

Also quoting higher votes answer (same Q/A):

> You can create a rule based on BCC you receive, but it's not
> immediately obvious as you have to resort to the message headers. The
> steps are:
>
> - Send yourself a BCC mail
> - When it arrives, open it up and display the "Properties" or "Message Options" dialog. You get to "Properties" under the File tab of the
>   ribbon. One way to get to message options is to click on the small
>   icon to the right of the "Tags" label on the Message tab of the
>   ribbon.
> - Scroll down the Internet headers until you find something that identifies it as BCC. In my case it was
>   X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Recipient-P2-Type: Bcc
> - Create a rule and choose "with specific words in the message header".
> - Copy in the value you found for step 3.
> - Save your rule, send yourself another BCC, and enjoy.

Comment: And if the sender does not use Exchange? Then what?

Comment: @Bib, first you have rule, independent of mail server. For second did you read carefully the text? **In my case it was.....**

Comment: @Bib, also you did not read the first 4 words of the question: **My outlook at work** At work for me in 99.9% of the cases mean Exchange.